# time user spent on the page

Tags: php, apache, nginx, logging

Is there a library or solution for quick apache/nginx log parsing and finding out how much time a user has spent on each page?

UPDATE: **spent on every 3rd level domain**.

For example AWStat can do that ( A full log analysis enables AWStats to show you the following information: Visits duration and last visits)

Comment: How would Apache know how long a user's on a page? All it can tell is when a request is made.

Comment: I know when user requested page, and if time between requests is more than X that means that user leaved site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache cannot do this. You can use jquery but it might not be accurate unless you perform long-polling on the page. Your question has been answered here in full on StackOverflow:

[How to measure a time spent on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page)

Comment: I can not modify site to add client side scripts (and as I know unload event doesn't work in Opera). Apache can not do that. But it is possible to calculate this. e.g. AWStats do that

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with log files... The log files don't log when a user leaves the page.  Youll need to use javascript for this using `onload()` and `onunload()`

Comment: You can extract a reasonably reliable time-of-departure by figuring out when the 'next' page was loaded. it fails for users who hold open multiple windows/tabs on the site, but works fairly well in general.

Comment: what happens if they go to one page then leave

Comment: I can not use javascript, and onload()/onunload() as i know doesn't work in Opera ("pinging" server is workaround for opera)

Answer (score 2):

Google analytics can help. It cannot determine how long a user was on the "last" page because it keeps track of when the user entered the next page to determine when they left the previous page.