# rails 3.1, tracking user time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to track the total time the student spend viewing his course pages, after logging, I am using devise gem.

I can store the DateTime.Now when the student starts watching a course, but, I have the following challenges to beat:

1. the student might open another window tab, leaving the course webpage, how can I pause time tracking while the student not viewing the course webpage, and resume tracking when he return?
2. to recognizing the student being idle for a certain time ?  ( doing nothing or even minimize the browser )

Any hint or help will be more than appreciated, 
is there a specific gem or jQuery plugin that can make the task easier ? 
or a recommend approach ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to measure a time spent on a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue you should take a look at onFocus and onBlur events.

```
window.onblur = function() {
  stopWatching();
};

window.onfocus = function() {
  startWatching();
};
```

For the second, i can't really help you but : you cant play with javascript events like mousemove or keypress.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: Thanks, I found a jQuery for checking mouse move or click, very nice, its here: http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer it even works when the window is not focused, but, still, I need a way to tell the rails to close session or do something

Comment: Cool plugin :) thanks for sharing. See the link of Benoit Garret you can send a request before unload with : $(window).unload(function() {