# How to add seconds up in database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

In my pageload I have a counter.

When it counts to 10, it has to add 10 seconds up in the database (update?),
after that the timer resets, when it reaches 10 seconds again, its has to add up another 10 seconds again in the database.

(so my database keeps track on how long I've been on my page)

What sql statement do I have to use for this?

Comment: which database and what you tried ?

Comment: Im using C#, and Acces Database, haven't tried anything (except the counter itself) because I have no clue where to start.

Comment: what kind of application? desktop or webapplication? do you use asp.net or something similar? and if it's a webapplication is it on the clientside or serverside? and and and...

Comment: Yes Im using asp.net, but Ive made the counter in C# it self: System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    TimeSpan ts = _sw.Elapsed;

Comment: with this stopwatch you can just measure the time you have to compute and deliver the page. i don't think your page will take 10seconds to load?

Comment: oh no, then Im not using the right timer I think, I want to count how long I was on the page for..

Comment: you should put what you have used in the code. then only others will come to know

Comment: if you want to measure the time someone spends on your site, you should use javascript and ajax or a websocket to update the time in your database. on the serverside you should program stateless.

Comment: Can you link me a spicif one for javascript + ajax?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you need. do you have a single page app or a normal one? anyway, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page I would go for the one with polling.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the Microsoft Access DateAdd function is:

DateAdd ( interval, number, date )

Parameters or Arguments

interval is the time/date interval that you wish to add. It can be one of the following values:

Value   Explanation
yyyy    Year
q   Quarter
m   Month
y   Day of the year
d   Day
w   Weekday
ww  Week
h   Hour
n   Minute
s   Second
number is the number of intervals that you wish to add.

date is the date to which the interval should be added.