# Track time spent by a user in a web page in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-views

I'm searching on how to track time spent by a user in a webpage of my django app.
I would like to store this time in the database in a column next to the username.
I've checked many solutions posted here but they seem very complicated for my app.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please show what you've found and describe why it's complicated? Maybe it's better to implement a tracker on a client side with JavaScript and DOM and send results before loading each page and before closing a page to the server which runs Django app?

Comment: Can you just place a repeating timer in your javascript that makes an AJAX call to your web service. At which time, the service updates the total time spent?

Comment: Thanx you guys for the feedback. I was following the example of TimeMe.js in this link:   [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page

Unfortunately I don't understand the part that the data collected from tracking are stored:

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("POST","ENTER_URL_HERE",false);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 var timeSpentOnPage = TimeMe.getTimeOnCurrentPageInSeconds();
 xmlhttp.send(timeSpentOnPage);
};