# Keep track on time spent on each page when a particular user visit a page and keep a record in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mongodb

I am stuck with the an issue in which I have to track a time spend by user on particular page and save data in database using mongodb.
I have seen one answer about the same but I am confused where to add that piece of code as I am using angularjs. Do I have to keep this code in controller of that particular page or to the index where I am rendering all code using ui-view.

Code from [How to measure a time spent on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page)

```
var start;

$(document).ready(function() {
  start = Date.getTime();

  $(window).unload(function() {
      end = Date.getTime();
      $.ajax({ 
        url: "log.php",
        data: {'timeSpent': end - start}
      })
   });
});
```

thnx in advance.

Comment: any reason why you can't use google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way I can think of to do this is to calculate the total amount of time in seconds spent by the user on a particular page by using the `$interval` service of angularjs.

First, initialise a `$scope` variable for the total seconds spent,

```
$scope.TotalSeconds = 0;
```

Then, a function to increment the variable,

```
var IncrementTotalSeconds = function()
{
    $scope.TotalSeconds += 1;
}
```

After that, use the `$interval` to increment the variable at every second.

```
$interval(IncrementTotalSeconds,1000);
```

Now you have the total seconds spent by the user on that particular page.

You can use the `$scope.TotalSeconds` to post the total time spent (in seconds) to the database.

**Note:** You can divide the Total Seconds if you want the time to be Minutes or Hours.