# Azure Application Insights to track time spent by user on webpage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

How can I use Azure Application Insights to track time spent by a user on webpage. In the javascript of the webpage, there is a chunk of code from application insights which we have to copy. I want to understand what

```
 r=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"]
```

means...Are there more parameters we can add to track some other stuff. Like if I wanted to track how long a user was on a webpage, how would I track that?

Comment: is it possible to find out the time spent by a user on a web page using azure insights? How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is built into the JavaScript SDK.

> By setting `autoTrackPageVisitTime: true`, the time a user spends on each page is tracked. On each new PageView, the duration the user spent on the previous page is sent as a custom metric named `PageVisitTime`. This custom metric is viewable in the Metrics Explorer as a "log-based metric".

You can find the documentation for it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#configuration-autotrackpagevisittime).

You pass the `autoTrackPageVisitTime` preference in the configuration object when creating your application insights instance.

```js
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
  connectionString: 'YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_GOES_HERE',
  autoTrackPageVisitTime: true,
  /* ...Other Configuration Options... */
} });
```

Comment: I don't see autoTrackPageVisitTime as a property in the configuration.  I figured it would be an option of    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions= new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();

Comment: If you do a word search, you can find "autoTrackPageVisitTime" on the page I linked. Please note that this is for the JavaScript SDK and is not compatible with ASP.net Core.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Custom Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#trackmetric)

Do your metric calculation using [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page) & pass it on like below to Application Insights.

```
appInsights.trackMetric("userstaytime", 42.0);
```

Comment: @KshitijAnilRangari thats just a hardcoded value rather than calculated value in this demonstration..

Comment: Just another question, in the link, appInsights.trackMetric("userstaytime", 42.0); Should be inside the ajax function...right ?