# How to print the time spent on a specific page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to print the time by an user on a specific page and print it. Actually I am want to create such type of google extension.

I found a link : [How to measure a time spent on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page)

BUt in that I am not getting how to print it in the extension?

Comment: You can use a *content script*. This question definitely was asked before so keep searching, and/or maybe inspect an existing extension that implements this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timeme.JS which is a javascript library that basically tracks the user's interation with the page. Below is the link for you to use it.
[jasonzissman/timeme.js](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js/)

Just clone it and run the index page of library. for implementation look at timeme.js file.