# There's a problem with a voicestateupdate in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want my bot to give coins to members that spent 1 minute in any voice channel. When I'm sitting in voice channel it's working good, but if I am quitting a channel, the bot still gives me 1 coin per minute. What did I do wrong?

I tried to stop a function when the user leaves a channel, tried to clear a timeout function, but it's still working that way:

```
bot.on("voiceStateUpdate",(oldMember,newMember)=>{
    let nuc = newMember.voiceChannel
    if(nuc !== undefined){ 
        function smth() {
            setTimeout(function coin() {
            db.add(`money_${newMember.id}`, 1)
            setTimeout(coin, 60000);
        }, 60000)}  
        smth()
        newMember.send('You're in voicechannel')
    } else {
        return newMember.send('You're out of voicechannel')
    }
})
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is why you are getting this behavior

Comment: you better add a handler for the event when you quit the channel and remove this

Comment: should I replace it with setInterval?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page