# Elasticsearch APM RUM Time on page / Session duration

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, apm, rum

Is there a way to make APM Real User Monitoring (Javascript agent) keep track of how long the user spent on the page?

I am currently using Elasticsearch v7.11.2

> I am aware that the time tracking is not in the list of current
> available features; is there is any way to do it
> through, for example using Transaction Spans or with pure JS?

Answer (score 2):

RUM mainly returns the [following data/metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/intro.html):

- Page load metrics
- Load time of Static Assets (JS, CSS, images, fonts, etc.)
- API requests (XMLHttpRequest and Fetch)
- Single page application navigations
- User interactions (click events that trigger network activity)
- User-centric metrics (Long tasks, FCP, LCP, FID, etc.)
- Page information (URLs visited and referrer)
- Network connection information
- JavaScript errors
- Distributed tracing
- Breakdown metrics

Time on page is not one of them. Also, there might be other metrics more interesting than time on page, such as [average session duration](https://www.hotjar.com/google-analytics/glossary/session-duration/) and [dwell time](https://www.semrush.com/blog/dwell-time/).

Since each transaction contains a duration in microseconds...

```
      "transaction" : {
        "duration" : {
          "us" : 17385392
        },
```

...you can use [well-known JS techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page) for detecting when a user lands on a page and when she leaves, and then you can leverage the [Transactions API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/transaction-api.html), in order to measure the time taken by a series of events while the user is on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am aware that the time tracking is not in the list of current available features; that's why I'm asking if there is any way to do it through for example using Transaction Spans or using pure JS.

Comment: Spans usually measure the time of single events. But using the [transaction API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/transaction-api.html) you're free to measure the time taken by a series of events while the user is on your page.